# SonarCube Update Version via REST

Tags: sonarqube

is it possible to set a version to a specific measure via REST call. Similar to the manual approach select a Project --> Configuration --> History --> Select specific measure --> Version create

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of events on a project for now (http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743167) but you cannot set new events via the REST API.

Feel free to follow and vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4085